# Prove an inequality based on a scalar product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, definite-integrals, vector-spaces, integral-inequality

> Let $V=\{f:[-\pi,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}| f\text{ continuous}\}$ with:
>
> $$f\times g=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)dx$$
>
> Show that $\forall f \in V$:
>
> $$\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\sin(x)dx\right|\leq\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(x)dx}$$

I tried showing this with the abosolute value property of the integral:

$$|\int_a^bf(x)dx|\leq\int_a^b|f(x)|dx$$

but it didn't work out.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Use the [Cauchy–Bunyakovsky–Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) inequality.

Comment: yup right, solved it, thanks!